# Content of component in Angular? <foo>content</foo>

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, viewchild, elementref

How do I get the contents of my current component?

Say I have `FooComponent` that's used in another component, like so:

```
<foo>bar</foo>
```

How do I extract `bar` in `FooComponent`?

Tried this, but got `val = null`:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.info('val =', this.elementRef.nativeElement.value);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe [Content Projection](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 access ng-content within component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545478/angular-2-access-ng-content-within-component)

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, found it:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML
```

And to the template add:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: yeah, you need to add a ng-content tag in template view to achieve this..
here is a proper example..
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Answer (score 0):

I've created one stackblitz for you in which I've created a tabs component and that tabs component has 3 tabs and I'm passing 3 different templates from app component to tabs component. I think this will give you a better understanding of passing data to a component and how to create a custom component.

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ck6nch?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts