# Get template from a ng-content's child

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement a select component with Angular 5. It consists of select component itself and option component. It should be used this way:

```
<app-select placeholder="Select smth">
  <app-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
    <img src="option.iconLocation"> {{ option.name }}
  </app-option>
</app-select>
```

If the value is not set, the user sees the placeholder, otherwise the user should see the exact content of the option he/she has selected, e.g. in that case image and text. So, how in `SelectComponent` can I access and render user specified template for the selected option?

The problem is not that I can't set the value with `@Output()`. It's the easy part. I want to render the value the same way the user of my `SelectComponent` specified in `<app-option/>`. An option should be able to contain anything inside (even another component, say `CardComponent`), and after the user has select a value, I want to show in the `SelectComponent` everything he/she saw in the option.

In `SelectComponent`'s template I have something like

```
<div [ngSwitch]="isEmpty" (click)="pp.toggle()">
    <button *ngSwitchCase="true">
        {{ placeholder }}
    </button>
    <button *ngSwitchDefault>
        THIS SHOULD TURN INTO 
        <img src="option.iconLocation"> {{ option.name }} 
        OR ANYTHING ELSE USER SPECIFIED IN THE OPTION COMPONENT
    </button>
</div>
<popup #pp>
    <ng-content>HERE GOES THE USER'S TEMPLATE</ng-content>
</popup>
```

[see an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arxyyp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html). How do I get this `<strong>{{ index }}</strong> {{ option.name }}` part and render inside the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@Output` decorator](https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2#eventemitter) with EventEmitter to emit the value to top-level components (use it in your `OptionComponent`).

It will emit the new value when it changes. So you can subscribe it in any top-level components.

For example with your code:

```
<app-select placeholder="Select smth">
  <app-option *ngFor="let option of options" 
              [value]="option" 
              (onOptionChanged)="onOptionChangedMethod($event)">
    <img src="option.iconLocation"> {{ option.name }}
  </app-option>
</app-select>
```

`onOptionChangedMethod(...)` could be located in your `SelectComponent` or anywhere else.

---

**EDIT:**

I forked your example, I guess this is a good start: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfqvqp**

Is that what you're looking for? I used `@ViewChild` to get the `ElementRef` of the transcluded `ng-content` that `app-option` uses.

Then, the emitted event now gives an object with the value, and the full `ElementRef` in order to inject it into `SelectComponent` that subscribes to this event.

N.B.: I don't know if it works well with components directly passed to `app-option` (it should), but I suggest you to take a look at "[angular 2 access ng-content within component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545566/2724204)".

Comment: Sorry, If my question was't clear enough. I updated it to be more specific about the problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry for misunderstanding! Could you show an example with https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular for example please? It'll be easier to help you :)

Comment: I updated my answer with simple reproduction. [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arxyyp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)