# How to check if ng-content was passed into the component?

Tags: angular

I have component with `ng-content` in it`s template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-cmp',
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`
})
export class SomeCmp {

}
```

So I can use it like that:

```
<some-cmp></some-cmp>

// or

<some-cmp>
  <span>xyz</span>
</some-cmp>
```

How to correctly check if somebody was passed as content or nothing was passed in the component?

I just need to check if anything is between `>` and `</` of my component selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Angular 2 how to check whether <ng-content> is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107211/in-angular-2-how-to-check-whether-ng-content-is-empty)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532829/angular-ng-content-how-to-find-element-inside

Answer (score 1):

If this is a styling based question, you can look into the `:empty` CSS selector