# How to add default layouts in angular6?

Tags: angular

**hello Everyone**
I want to add default layout to be the main layout of all my angular components ,

eg. Layout for main pages and layout for login pages.
If it is available to make that?
If not , what is the best way to handle this matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by define `<layout>` component (which will use `<ng-content>`) which will be used by all components in this way

Some component template:

```
<layout>
    <div> Some component content... </div>
</layout>
```

The layout component template can look like that as very simple example (you need to add it to app.module.ts as any other component):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'layout',
    providers: [],
    styleUrls: [ './layout.component.css' ],
    templateUrl: './layout.component.html'
})

export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit
{    
    
    constructor()
    {}

    public ngOnInit()
    {        
        
    }
}
```

```css
.layout {}
.layout-head {}
.layout-body{}
.layout-footer{}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
    <div class="layout-head"></div>
    <div class="layout-body">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I add this ?

Comment: @AhmedSakr I updae answer (create layout component as regular component)

Comment: Can you provide a full example please?

Comment: Your answer is good and worked with me ..but in you opinion what is best way to pass styles and scripts from component to layout component..

Comment: @AhmedSakr The layout component use <ng-content></ng-content> which means that any content (components) which will be between <layout>here</layout> tag will be automatically included into layout (you don't need to do it by hand). So above snippet there is pice of code (template) with example of usage layout in other component.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved in atleast 2 ways:

- by implementing routes and having a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside the template of a component which holds the default layout https://angular.io/guide/router
- by using content projection on a component holding the default layout by using `<ng-content></ng-content>` [angular 2 access ng-content within component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545478/angular-2-access-ng-content-within-component)

Good luck!

Comment: Great, but can you provide a full example please?

Comment: I have provided links to the official documentation with examples and to a stack overflow thread which explains with examples both scenarios. This should help you get started. If you have problems implementing show your implementation so we can help you further